# Need to display alert message using Angular4 after clicking a checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, alert

I am new to Angular 4 framework. I need to show an alert message or pop up on clicking a checkbox. I am not getting any proper answer how to do it.

below is the html snippet which I need to click

```
<td width="15%">
            <p-checkbox value ="Active" label="Active" [(ngModel)]="status">
 </p-checkbox>
</td>
```

what I need to add in as component or in any other ts? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is :

```
<p-checkbox value ="Active" label="Active" [(ngModel)]="status" (onChange)='alert("changed")'>
```

For more details , please read :

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox

Comment: Thanks Vivek ji for ur answer. But I want a pop up to be displayed.

Comment: For popup you should just change popup modal property to show onChange event.

Comment: Thanks Vivek Doshi for the link https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox. It helped me.

Comment: @user3705879 , glad to here that :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the HTML to display a dialog:

```
<td width="15%">
  <p-checkbox value ="Active" label="Active" [(ngModel)]="status">
  </p-checkbox>
</td>
<p-dialog header="Warning" [(visible)]="status">
  Warning !
</p-dialog>
```